# Как в django jinja html вписать {% static '...' %} в {% with ... %}

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, jinja2, django-filter

Хочу сделать вот так:

```
{% with a as {% static '...' %} %}
{% with a={{ b }} %}
{% static {{ a }} %}
```

Как так сделать??? Оно не работает(

Comment: Еще не получается сделать так: `{% with a='...'+'...' %}`

Comment: В Jinja нет `{% static %}`. Вы шаблонизаторы не путаете?